# Can we create IM clients other than GTalk using Smack api in Android?

Tags: android, smack

For the past two weeks, i am working to create an application, which is used to communicate with all Messengers in Android.

I am using the Smack API for that, and now I can connect to GTalk.

Now trying to connect it to the Yahoo messenger.

But it is throwing some exception.

I want to know whether we can create Yahoo IM client using Smack API or not.

If possible please give the list of IM clients supported by Smack API.

Answer (score 4):

According to the Smack website, "Smack is an Open Source XMPP (Jabber) client library for instant messaging and presence.". Yahoo! Messenger uses a non-compatible proprietary protocol. Wikipedia has a list of instant messaging clients based on the XMPP protocol at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XMPP_client_software.